# Unable to find an entry point named 'MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStreamEx' in DLL 'mfplat.dll'

Tags: c#, .net, naudio, naudio-framework

We are using NAudio for MP4 to MP3 conversion. We are getting this error only for few MP4 files (not all MP4 files have this problem).

> Unable to find an entry point named 'MFCreateMFByteStreamOnStreamEx'
>   in DLL 'mfplat.dll'

The part of the code where this error is appearing:

```
_mfReader = new MediaFoundationReader(_mp4Bytes);
```

Where ***_mfReader*** is an instance of MediaFoundationReader class and ***_mp4Bytes*** is a byte arrray of the MP4 file. I googled and found another problem related to *mfplat.dll* but that is about DLL loading error and not the entry point problem. Please help me fix this error.

Comment: [NAudio issue 176](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio/issues/176)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to avoid this error by running my code on Windows 10. Looks like there is a codec that is not available in Windows 7 and previous versions of windows. Windows 8 and above have this codec.